# selecting last 2 max from same telephone

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

```
select  t3.tn, t1.parent_trans_id 
  from  T1 
  INNER JOIN 
   T2
  ON T1.SL_ORDER_ID = t2.sl_order_id 
  inner join 
   t3
  on t2.subscriber_line_id = t3.subscriber_line_id
  where 

t3.TN in ('9727740700', '9897860312')
```

This is the query I am using to bring below data

```
TN             parent_trans_id
9897860312      166974063
9897860312      168516881
9897860312      168486626
9727740700      172254571
9727740700      173345705
9727740700      173345235
```

I need to select only last 2 max of parent_trans_id I tried some sub_queries but didn't work.
Below is the data set which I need.

```
    TN          parent_trans_id
9897860312       168516881
9897860312       168486626
9727740700       173345705
9727740700       173345235
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use analytic function `row_number` to assign row numbers within each group and get top two rows for each tn.

```
select *
from (
    select t3.tn,
        t1.parent_trans_id,
        row_number() over (
            partition by t3.tn order by t1.parent_trans_id desc nulls last
            ) rn
    from T1
    inner join T2 on T1.SL_ORDER_ID = t2.sl_order_id
    inner join t3 on t2.subscriber_line_id = t3.subscriber_line_id
    where t3.TN in ('9727740700', '9897860312')
    )
where rn <= 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by tn order by ?? desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

The `??` is for a column that specifies what "last" is.